# How to make the text overflow the backrgound from top and bottom?

Tags: css

I'm trying to emulate this behavior using CSS:

[image: text over a red transparent div]

And this is what I have to this moment:

```css
.contenedor{
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
}
.lineaRoja{
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 20px;  
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;      
}
.centreado{  
  font-size: 30px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
    <div class="lineaRoja">
        <h2 class="centreado">Streaming</h2>    
    </div>                        
</div>
```

How can I get that CSS behavior?

Comment: Did you want the text to look like [this](https://i.postimg.cc/L8ZgHP9P/Screenshot-2020-01-29-at-16.png) or [this?](https://i.postimg.cc/x8xNdyNv/Screenshot-2020-01-29-at-16-07-16.png)

Comment: @Jamessaystrytopanswers.xyz The second one. Though the answers I recieved for the first one are good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another idea where you can consider `line-height`

```css
h2 {
   background: #f16c73;
   color: #fff;
   font: 2.4em Arial;
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: 800;
   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   line-height:0.45; 
   /*overflow:hidden; uncomment this if you want to hide the overflow */
 }
```

```html
<h2>STREAMING</h2>
```

Another one where you can adjust the background:

```css
h2 {
   color: #fff;
   font: 2.4em Arial;
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: 800;
   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   background: 
    linear-gradient(#f16c73,#f16c73) center
    /100% 45%  /* Adjust this value */
    no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<h2>STREAMING</h2>
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, just what I needed.

line-height:0.5

Answer (score 3):

I would cut the upper and lower part via `clip-path`. No need to use extra elements or pseudoelements

```css
h2 {
   background: #f16c73;
   color: #fff;
   font: 2.4em Arial;
   font-style: italic;
   font-weight: 800;
   text-align: center;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
   clip-path: polygon(20% 33%, 20% 70%, 80% 70%, 80% 33%);  
 }
```

```html
<h2>STREAMING</h2>
```

Comment: Worked, Thank you.

Comment: This is a great answer, but I don't think it works the way the OP wanted. Closer inspection of the image that OP posted reveals that the text outside of the red box is still visible. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXInr.png

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use opacity, but simply white text and white background. The text can be vertically positioned by using `postion: relative` and a `bottom` setting to offset it to the optimal position.

```css
.contenedor {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.lineaRoja {
  background-color: red;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.centreado {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-style: oblique;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="lineaRoja">
    <h2 class="centreado">STREAMING</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to move the text via transform property of CSS.

```css
.contenedor {
  height: 30px;
}

.lineaRoja {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0 ,0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.centreado {
  font-size: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateY(-40%);
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="lineaRoja">
    <h2 class="centreado">Streaming</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the text colour to transparent and set the font style to italic.

```
    .centreado{  
      font-size: 60px;  
      color: transparent;
      font-style: italic;
    }
```

Move the div downwards.

```
.contenedor{
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;  
  transform: translateY(20px); /*Change this value according to your need */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
   <div class="contenedor">
      <div class="lineaRoja">
        <h2 class="centreado">Streaming</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.contenedor {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.lineaRoja {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.centreado {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 38px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0
}
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hansfelix50/q0zxh9ku/

Answer (score 0):

The secret here is `overflow: hidden;` on your red line, anything overflowing it gets cut off.

```css
.contenedor {
  height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.lineaRoja {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.centreado {
  font-size: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="lineaRoja">
    <h2 class="centreado">Streaming</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with [css flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Steps:

1. Remove the `opacity: 0.5;` and `text-align: center;` from `.lineaRoja`
2. Add `background-color: #f36167;` to `.lineaRoja`
3. Add `display: flex; align-items: center; justify content: center;` to `.lineaRoja`
4. Style the `h1` as necessary; I've used: `letter-spacing: 2px;  font-size: 55px; font-family: arial; font-style: italic; color: white;`

Here is a simple example using:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.lineaRoja {
  background-color: #f36167;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.centreado {
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family: arial;
  font-style: italic;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="lineaRoja">
  <h1 class="centreado">STREAMING</h1>    
</div>
```